# KineticJS, preserving layer data on stage redraw

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a canvas with multiple layers. One layer is for drawing and others have the tools for it.. I am able to click on a tool and apply it to the main layer. So far its working fine but now i want to add the re-size functionality.. If the window re-size I will simply redraw the stage {by calling the init function} and it would be drawn with the screen proportions that's not an issue but, I am unable to preserve the Main Layer. I tried to use toJSON function, was wondering to get the layer data in a variable and redraw the stage and then with some logic redraw the layer with the JSON data with some modifications in the dimensions but am unable to load the layer with the JSON data.

This is my Main Layer code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "container",
    width: document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth,
    //width: 1000,
    height: document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight
});

var canvasContainer = new Kinetic.Layer({
            x: stage.getX(),
            y: stage.getY(),
            width: ((stage.getWidth() / 100 ) * 30), //stage.getWidth() > 600 ? ((stage.getWidth() / 100 ) * 30) : 300,
            height: stage.getHeight(),
            draggable: false,

        });
```

Can anyone please help me in getting it done?

Regards
Junaid

Comment: Your approach of using toJSON and recreate should work, I have used it in past. So try to put in that code and highlight the specific problem that is happening when you are trying to recreate. A fiddle would be best!

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use the `toJSON` method to preserve `Kinetic.Shape` inside a container (in this case the `canvasContainer` layer). To test it, see what outputs when you do this:

`console.log(canvasContainer.toJSON());`

You can recreate the layer from the json string like this:

```
var json = canvasContainer.toJSON();
canvasContainer = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
```

**But**, why do you need to redraw/reinitialise the stage when all you're doing is resizing it? Instead what I would do is use the `setSize` function on the stage:

```
//After Code to resize window or #container
var newWidth = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
var newHeight = document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight;
stage.setSize(newWidth, new Height);
stage.draw();
```

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#setSize